# LcoationChanged is not calling when activity goes to pause or stop when application in stack in android Oreo Version

Tags: android, location, google-api-client

As I'm using googleapiclient in my activity to fetch location but when app is in foreground means onlocationchanged method is working so I'm getting location.
When app is in pause or stop state means location is not getting in android Oreo version.When activity goes to destroy state means ok we wont get location because is in background,when app in pause or stop state means either it should be goes to other activity or in stack.

Service only wont call when app goes to sleep mode, but activity need to work  when is in pause or stop state right? but its not working in my application .Please help me to fix my issue.

```
public class UserHomePage extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, View.OnClickListener,GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener {

    Thread t;
    private Location mylocation;
    private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
    private final static int REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS_GPS=0x1;
    private final static int REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS=0x2;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    private RequestQueue requestQueue,requestQueue1,requestQueue2,requestQueue3,requestQueue4;

    String gs_var_fcm;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.user_activity_home);
        ctx=this;
     setUpGClient();

        mapboxToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mapboxToolbar);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Log.i("WW","--onPause");

        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Log.i("WW","--onStop");


        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();


        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }


   private synchronized void setUpGClient() {
        googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this, 0, this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        googleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        mylocation = location;
        if (mylocation != null) {
            Log.i("QES","onlocation"+mylocation);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        checkPermissions();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        //Do whatever you need
        //You can display a message here
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        //You can display a message here
    }

    private void getMyLocation(){
        if(googleApiClient!=null) {
            if (googleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                int permissionLocation = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(UserHomePage.this,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
                if (permissionLocation == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    mylocation =                     LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient);
                    LocationRequest locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
                    locationRequest.setInterval(3000);
                    locationRequest.setFastestInterval(3000);
                    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
                    LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
                            .addLocationRequest(locationRequest);
                    builder.setAlwaysShow(true);
                    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi
                            .requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, locationRequest, this);
                    PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result =
                            LocationServices.SettingsApi
                                    .checkLocationSettings(googleApiClient, builder.build());
                    result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult result) {
                            final Status status = result.getStatus();
                            switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                                    // All location settings are satisfied.
                                    // You can initialize location requests here.
                                    int permissionLocation = ContextCompat
                                            .checkSelfPermission(UserHomePage.this,
                                                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
                                    if (permissionLocation == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                                        mylocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi
                                                .getLastLocation(googleApiClient);
                                        if(mylocation!=null)
                                        {
                                            Log.i("QES","permissionlocation"+mylocation);

                                            //  Toast.makeText(UserHomePage.this, "mylocation"+mylocation, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            gs_str_latitude = String.valueOf(mylocation.getLatitude());
                                            gs_str_Longitude = String.valueOf(mylocation.getLongitude());
                                            sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("myprefer", MODE_PRIVATE);
                                            editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

                                            editor.putString("dest_Lat", gs_str_latitude);
                                            editor.putString("dest_Long", gs_str_Longitude);
                                            editor.putString("Lat", gs_str_latitude);
                                            editor.putString("Long", gs_str_Longitude);

                                            editor.commit();

                                            GS_UserUpdateLocation(gs_str_latitude, gs_str_Longitude, strlevel, Date, networkinformation);

                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            //  Toast.makeText(UserHomePage.this, "mylocation", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                        }

                                    }
                                    break;
                                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                                    // Location settings are not satisfied.
                                    // But could be fixed by showing the user a dialog.
                                    try {
                                        // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                                        // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                                        // Ask to turn on GPS automatically
                                        status.startResolutionForResult(UserHomePage.this,
                                                REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS_GPS);
                                    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                                        // Ignore the error.
                                    }
                                    break;
                                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                                    // Location settings are not satisfied.
                                    // However, we have no way
                                    // to fix the
                                    // settings so we won't show the dialog.
                                    // finish();
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS_GPS:
                switch (resultCode) {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        getMyLocation();
                        break;
                    case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                        finish();
                        break;
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    private void checkPermissions(){
        int permissionLocation = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(UserHomePage.this,
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        List<String> listPermissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<>();
        if (permissionLocation != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
            if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty()) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        listPermissionsNeeded.toArray(new String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()]), REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
            }
        }else{
            getMyLocation();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        int permissionLocation = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(UserHomePage.this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        if (permissionLocation == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            getMyLocation();
        }
    }
```

Note:Eventhough I give googleapiclient is connected only when pause,stop,resume,start state,eventhough its not showing.
please help me

Comment: *...but activity need to work when is in pause or stop state right?* **No**

Comment: yes below oreo version is working.but in oreo version is not working

Answer (score 0):

From Oreo, Google has added restrictions to get location when app is in background. You can read [changes introduced in Oreo](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background-location-limits) here.

What you can do is create a foreground service for Location update so that when your app goes to background you can receive Location updates normally.

Comment: That for service only right? why normal activity also wont run in pause or stop state ah.App in stack only right?

Comment: when mobile goes to sleep mode,service only wont call right? but activity location also not updating

Comment: *why normal activity also wont run in pause or stop state ah.App in stack only right?* because it is one of the android basics - **Activity should not run when it is on pause (or later  state)** ...